# How can I change the row height some particular row in DataGridView?

Tags: c#

I have a grid view..in that i have a image column..

when ever image coming to image column i want to increase my row height programatically

How can I change the row height some particular row in DataGridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [AutoSizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[2];
column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
```

This will automaticly size it to fit.

Comment: this is oke sir,,but i have one more doubt

Comment: in my data grid view 6th column is the image column ,,so i need to check wethar particular column have image or not..so i given code like this:if (!Information.IsDBNull(gv.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value) && gv.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString.Length != 0)

Comment: but that code is not working proper,,if not having image also coming inside the if loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataGridViewRow.Height`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.height%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
myGrid.CurrentRow.Height = someValue;
```

Comment: i want to increase height wethar that row contains images

Comment: in my 6th column i am showing image,,i want that image look like stretchable?

Comment: @user3226387 if you want to change the height of particular row, you should know it's index, then you can do it like this `myGrid.Rows[index].Height = newValue;`.

Comment: yup.correct..i already got ...in my 6th column showing image,how i can show that image more clear?

Comment: @user3226387, when you're dealing with [`DataGridViewImageCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecell.aspx), you can use [`ImageLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecell.imagelayout.aspx) property and set it to the value from [`DataGridViewImageCellLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecelllayout.aspx) enumeration. But originally quality depends on the image itself, its  resolution etc.